# modeling 2 relationships A many B, A many C, where optionally B has many C and both with same A

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework, relational-database

I have a Clients table that has the ClientName attribute, which is also the primary key.

I have a Iterations table, that has a foreign key to ClientName and another attribute, called IterationId. The pair (ClientName, IterationId) is the primary key of this table.

A third table must exist, with the following characteristics:

1. a foreign key to ClientName, not nullable.
2. an IterationId, which is an nullable attribute, and should be a foreign key to the Iterations table.

Since requirement 2 implies using also a foreign key to the ClientName attribute of the Iterations table, this third table should have, at least, 3 attributes, namely (ClientName1, ClientName2, IterationId), where ClientName1 is a foreign key to the Clients table and (ClientName2, IterationId) is a foreign key to the Iterations table. Furthermore, I need to guarantee that ClientName1 == ClientName2, always.

Is there a proper way to model these 3 tables in order to guarantee all the requirements just described?

Edit:
in a object-oriented world, this could easily me modeled in the following way:

```
public class Client{

public List<Iteration> Iterations;
public List<Entity3> ListOfEntity3;

}

public class Iteration{

public List<Entity3> ListOfEntity3;

[NotNull]
public Client ClientReference;
}

public class Entity3 {

[NotNull]
public Client ClientReference;


public Iteration IterationReference;//this can be null.

}
```

For every instance I of Entity3, if I.IterationReference!=null then I.IterationReference.ClientReference == I.ClientReference.

how do I achieve this in a relational world?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a Foreign Key mapping back to table1 in your table3, Since you will have a Foreign Key in table3 mapping back to Table2 and Table2 has a Foreign Key mapping back to Table1, In your third table all you need is a Foreign Key mapping back to Table2 and some surrogate Key in table3 so you can have multiple Cs referencing back to one record in table2.

Comment: I really dont get it... what is an "C"?

Comment: C I am referring to records in table3

Comment: But in this solution, how do I map an "C" back to table 1? Note that the map from "C" to table 2 is optional (foreign key is nullable).

Comment: This table3 records are mapped back to Table2, Table2 mapped back to table1, so any records in Table3 are actually mapped back to table1 via table2, you dont need a column in table3 directly referencing back to table1.

Comment: Im afraid I still dont get it. How a table3 record will map to a table1 record without mapping to a table2 record? (this is a requirement)

Comment: in this case if you could add some data to your question and show with an example what you are trying to achieve.